# Let$\ PA_n $ be the$\ n $-th odd primitive abundant number (whose divisors are deficient). An upper bound for $\ {\sigma(PA_n) \over PA_n} $?

Tags: number-theory

Very clearly,$$\ \lim_{n\to\infty}{\sigma(PA_n) \over PA_n}=2. $$
I need whatever $\ m $ such that for every$\ n $, $\ {\sigma(PA_n) \over PA_n} < m $. I've tried with no success, but I think it should be reasonably easy, especially with some tool that I probably lack, or maybe an intuition I failed to have up to now. Here is a table that leaves neither doubt of the limit, nor of the existence of$\ m $, which in fact is most likely just$\ 3 $ (but I'm **not** necessarily demanding the best upper bound):

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
n & \text{$\ PA_n$} & \text{$\ \sigma(PA_n)$} & \text{$\ {\sigma(PA_n) \over PA_n}$} \\
\hline
1 & 945 & 1920 &  \frac{128}{63}\approx 2.03175 \\
2 & 1575 & 3224 & \frac{3224}{1578}\approx 2.04698  \\
3 & 2205 & 4446 & \frac{494}{245}\approx 2.01633 \\
4 & 3465 & 7488 & \frac{832}{285}\approx 2.16104 \\
5 &  4095 & 8736 & \frac{32}{15}\approx 2.13333 \\
6 & 5355 & 11232 & \frac{1248}{595}\approx 2.09748 \\
7 & 5775 & 11904 & \frac{3968}{1925}\approx 2.0613 \\
8 & 5985 & 12480 & \frac{832}{399} \approx 2.08521 \\
9 & 6435 & 13104 & \frac{112}{55}\approx 2.03636 \\
10 & 6825 & 13888 & \frac{1984}{975}\approx 2.03487 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
10000 & 159210675 & 318595680 & \frac{554608}{272155}\approx 2.00109 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\end{array}
$$

You can find the first 10000 odd primitive abundant numbers [here](http://oeis.org/A006038/b006038.txt).
Any ideas as to the bound?

Comment: Why is it clear that the limit equals $2$, or even exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma**: Let $n>1$ be an integer, and let $p$ be the largest prime dividing $n$. Then
$$
\frac{\sigma(n)}n \le \bigg(1+\frac1p\bigg) \frac{\sigma(n/p)}{n/p}.
$$

**Proof**: Write $n=p^rm$ where $p\nmid m$. Then
$$
\frac{\sigma(n)/n}{\sigma(n/p)/(n/p)} = \frac{\sigma(p^rm)}{p\sigma(p^{r-1}m)} = \frac{\sigma(p^r)\sigma(m)}{p\sigma(p^{r-1})\sigma(m)} = \frac{\sigma(p^r)}{p\sigma(p^{r-1})}.
$$
Since $\sigma(p^r) = \frac{p^{r+1}-1}{p-1}$, this gives
$$
\frac{\sigma(n)/n}{\sigma(n/p)/(n/p)} = \frac{p^{r+1}-1}{p(p^r-1)} \le \frac{p+1}p = 1+\frac1p.
$$

As a consequence, if $n$ is a primitive abundant number whose largest prime factor is $p$, then
$$
\frac{\sigma(n)}n \le 2\bigg(1+\frac1p\bigg).
$$
Odd primitive abundant numbers have to be divisible by at least three distinct primes; this immediately gives an upper bound of $m=2(1+\frac17) = \frac{16}7 \approx 2.286$.

One can do better with a little computation. For example, the only odd primitive abundant numbers not divisible by a prime exceeding $7$ are $945$, $1575$, and $2205$. A calculation gives $\frac{\sigma(n)}n \le 2.05$ for these, and the above argument gives an upper bound of $m=2(1+\frac1{11}) = \frac{24}{11} \approx 2.182$ for the rest.

Probably the best possible upper bound is $m+\frac{32}{15} = 2.1333\dots$, which is achieved by $n=4095$. Since $2(1+\frac1{17}) = \frac{35}{17} < \frac{32}{15}$, this would follow from an exhaustive calculation of all primitive abundant numbers of the form $3^a5^b7^c11^d13^e$ and checking that their $\frac{\sigma(n)}n$ values never exceed $\frac{32}{15}$.

(Once one shows that there are only finitely many primitive abundant numbers with prime factors bounded by any given $B$, this argument then does show that the limit equals $2$, as asserted.)

Comment: Thank you! You actually proved both the limit and the best bound, great answer! I would have a question regarding odd primitive abundant numbers and its odd multiples. That is, I'd like to know whether the former satisfying a certain inequality, imply the former too. My guess is yes, and I even have some arguments for it, but I don't know if it is enough. I'm posting an other question, answer it if you can. Again, thank you.

Comment: LATE EDIT: *latter too

Comment: Here is the other question, if you desire: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928532/consider-the-inequality-sigmaii-log-log-2m-i-if-an-odd-primitive-abu

Comment: Oh, by the way, perhaps I couldn't help but fail to see a little mistake in your answer. I guess the best possible upper bound is$\ \frac{832}{385}\approx 2.16104$, reached by$\ n=3465$, and one can verify it by checking that$\ \frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$ for all$\ n$ of the form$\ 3^a 5^b 7^c 11^d$ never exceeds$\ \frac{832}{385}$, since$\ 2\left(1+\frac{1}{13}\right)=\frac{28}{13}<\frac{832}{385}$, right?

Comment: (also, in the first comment: *their odd multiples. Not my best comment, I suppose)

Comment: Yes, $n=3465$ is better and so my "probably best upper bound" is clearly false; and you're write about how to verify it (assuming the numerical inequality which I didn't check). Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

See my paper

> *On primitive abundant numbers*, J. Austral. Math. Soc. (Ser. A), 34 (1983), 123-137, [link](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S1446788700019819)

for answers to this question and much more. In particular, the upper bound $2.16104$ for primitive abundant numbers is proved (Theorem 5).